# 'Toolbars' missing in the 'Configure' menu in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio

I just installed and started using TeXStudio for Windows and found that few of the items in the "Configure" menu that are described in the user manual are simply missing. In particular the item "Toolbars" is missing.
What might be the reason for that? And how do I create custom toolbar in this situation?

Comment: Observe that there should be a check box for Advanced in the Configure window. See left bottom corner of the window.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. The problem was that when one increases the font size to a number greater than 8 (which I did in the very beginning) the bottom part of the Configure window  simply doesn't show up.

Comment: To see the whole window, maximize it.